# When copy/paste, I would like to capture both leading and trailing spaces

Tags: javascript, arrays

Currently I have a requirement to help solve a problem. Our users have to add a company ID that may have both leading and trailing spaces. Currently, they have to tab through 10 boxes to enter the company ID. I would like a spot where they could copy from a spreadsheet, application, etc, and that value get parsed out into the 10 boxes automagically. The company ID could be numbers, spaces, letters, and special characters with leading, within, or trailing spaces BUT has to be 10 characters long.

This has been a thorn in my side for a while now and I am hoping the community can help me.

Here is the script so far.

```
var aView = Screen.CurrentView;
var str = aView.Fields("CompanyIDPaste").Value;
var strLen = str.length;
if (strLen < 10){
    var str2 = "1111111111";
    var str3 = str2.concat(str);
    var str = str3.substring(str3.length - 10, str3.length);
}
var arr1 = str.slice(0, 1);
var arr2 = str.slice(1, 2);
var arr3 = str.slice(2, 3);
var arr4 = str.slice(3, 4);
var arr5 = str.slice(4, 5);
var arr6 = str.slice(5, 6);
var arr7 = str.slice(6, 7);
var arr8 = str.slice(7, 8);
var arr9 = str.slice(8, 9);
var arr10 = str.slice(9, 10);
if (strLen < 10){
    aView.Fields("a1").Value = '';
} else {
    aView.Fields("a1").Value = arr1;
}
if (strLen < 9){
    aView.Fields("a2").Value = '';
} else {
    aView.Fields("a2").Value = arr2;
}
if (strLen < 8){
    aView.Fields("a3").Value = '';
} else {
    aView.Fields("a3").Value = arr3;
}
if (strLen < 7){
    aView.Fields("a4").Value = '';
} else {
    aView.Fields("a4").Value = arr4;
}
if (strLen < 6){
    aView.Fields("a5").Value = '';
} else {
    aView.Fields("a5").Value = arr5;
}
if (strLen < 5){
    aView.Fields("a6").Value = '';
} else {
    aView.Fields("a6").Value = arr6;
}
if (strLen < 4){
    aView.Fields("a7").Value = '';
} else {
    aView.Fields("a7").Value = arr7;
}
if (strLen < 3){
    aView.Fields("a8").Value = '';
} else {
    aView.Fields("a8").Value = arr8;
}
if (strLen < 2){
    aView.Fields("a9").Value = '';
} else {
    aView.Fields("a9").Value = arr9;
}
if (strLen < 1){
    aView.Fields("a10").Value = '';
} else {
    aView.Fields("a10").Value = arr10;
}
```

This helped with keeping leading spaces, but trailing spaces got truncated. SO for example,
_ _ 345_abc_ would be truncated to _ _ _ 345_abc as the value and that is not correct. I need it to parse out EXACTLY as it is copied/pasted into the field.

This is driving me nuts. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: IDs that include leading and/or trailing spaces is _horrible_ design.

Comment: That said, if it's only the trailing spaces getting truncated, simply append spaces to the string until it is 10 characters long. (But again, and I cannot stress this enough, this is _horrible_ design for string IDs.)

Comment: Yeah, thank the gov't for that. I am not  fan either, but _ _ _ 4567_ 9_ is not the same at _ _ _ _ 4567_9 ...two separate company IDs. Yuck.

Comment: And how would you append spaces to get to 10 characters prior to slicing them?

Comment: `str = str.padEnd(10);`

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of a dingy hack, but if you use autotab (jquery) on the page and set focus to the first box, a user doing a paste will get the 10 characters distributed across the fields as long as they are all limited to 1 character of input each. Anything in excess of 10 characters will get dropped in the aether.

If they type their ID in the autotab will take them from box to box as long as the field size is limited to 1 character.